# PowerShell Tee-Object also verbose logging

Tags: powershell, console, stderr

I use Tee-Object to output my command to console and a file. I use this command:

```
Command 2>&1 | Tee-Object 'myfile.log'
```

With this command I only get standard and error output in my file. When a verbose output is send I do see it in the console but it doesn't end up in my logfile.

How can I output alle console info to a file? So also verbose messages.

I found this

```
 Pipeline (1) 
 Error    (2) 
 Warning  (3) 
 Verbose  (4) 
 Debug    (5)
 All      (*)

We still use the same operators
 >    Redirect to a file and replace contents
 >>   Redirect to a file and append to existing content
 >&1  Merge with pipeline output
```

So Command *> 'myfile.log' 
does the trick for my file but I don't see output in the console this way

Comment: Yes that works.Maybe give it as an answer so I can accept it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually already pretty close to your answer.

if that one worked `Command 2>&1 | Tee-Object 'myfile.log'` and you already found out that `*` instead of `2` would log everything, just do it that way:

```
Command *>&1 | Tee-Object 'myfile.log'
```